# Prevent multiple instances of an object

Tags: php, object, constructor

I have a superclass which instantiates my Sql class so all derived classes will be able to perform queries without instantiating their own Sql instances once they are constructed.
This works good but I have a question I'm confusing myself about. One of the derived classes instantiates another derived class in its constructor so now, I believe I have 2 instances of the Sql class open because each instantiates the parent. I cannot override the parent class in any of the derived classes because they all need access to a a database instance to perform their own queries. Is there a way to prevent the derived class from calling the parent constructor when another derived class instantiates it?

I'm thinking passing a parameter to the class and only calling the parent constructor if meets the requirements as such.

```
function__construct($param) {
    if($param == false) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
 }
```

Do you think this approach makes sense, or do you forsee any bugs arising in the future?

Comment: You're looking for the singleton pattern http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+singleton+

Comment: Why should you have more than one instance in your application if you only instantiate it once? (regarding the fear you have). Next to that, calling the parent's constructor method is *not* creating an additional instance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @Michael: The singleton is an Anti-Pattern.

Comment: @hakre we could debate that for a long time. The reality is, it has a couple of appropriate uses amidst numerous inappropriate ones, and one of those appropriate uses is managing access to a database connection abstraction object or configuration object.

Comment: I would put the use-case into an in-appropriate one regarding the kind of problem Naterade describes in his own code (even not yet using singletons). It's another classical example how one God-like Superclass makes your code not really useable. The debate is fine, and global variables do actually a job, too. Question is what do you do when you run into problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is using the singleton pattern. To do that, you should just declare your constructor as a private method:

```
private function __construct() {

}
```

and initialize it once by calling a static method for example:

```
static function connect_to_mysql() {
    //procedure of connecting...
}

myClass::connect_to_mysql();
```

Comment: Hmm...I may try the singleton pattern. Let me see how it works out for me and I'll get back to you!